# Translation Golf XVI - Los que se van de Omelas

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

Bienvenidos al festival del solsticio de Omelas, la utópica y reluciente ciudad de increíble felicidad y placer. Omelas tiene pocas leyes, pues sus habitantes, inteligentes, sofisticados y cultos, tienen poca necesidad de ellas. Omelas carece de reyes, sacerdotes, soldados o esclavos. Los habitantes de Omelas son gentes auténticamente felices.

Sé que Omelas suena en mis palabras como una ciudad de un cuento de hadas. ¿Creen ustedes todo esto? ¿Aceptan la realidad de esta celebración, de esta ciudad, de esta alegría? ¿No? Entonces déjenme describirles algo más. El precio de la felicidad de Omelas.

> They all know it is there, all the people of Omelas. Some of them have come to see it, others are content merely to know it is there. They all know that it has to be there. Some of them understand why, and some do not, but they all understand that their happiness, the beauty of their city, the tenderness of their friendships, the health of their children, the wisdom of their scholars, the skill of their makers, even the abundance of their harvest and the kindly weathers of their skies, depend wholly on this child's abominable misery.

Posible traducción al español (386 caracteres):

> Todos saben que está allá, todos los habitantes de Omelas. Algunos han venido a verlo, otros se contentan simplemente con saber que está ahí. Algunos comprenden por qué, otros no, pero todos comprenden que su felicidad, la belleza de su ciudad, el afecto de sus relaciones, la salud de sus hijos, la sabiduría de sus sabios, el talento de sus artistas, incluso la abundancia de sus cosechas y la clemencia de su clima dependen completamente de la abominable miseria de aquel niño.

Esto es [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf), la traducción con menor número de caracteres que respete el sentido del texto original gana.

---

- Recordatorio de las normas: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Link para contar caracteres: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

---

[The Ones Who Walk Away from Omelas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ones_Who_Walk_Away_from_Omelas) (en español, [Los que se van de Omelas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_que_se_alejan_de_Omelas)) es un relato corto de Ursula K. Le Guin. Sus descripciones, a la vez vagas y vívidas, presentan una buena selección de fragmentos que harían buen material para el [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf).

El fragmento que he escogido es un poco largo, pero aprovecho que es el último [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) del verano, y alguno anda aburrido y con tiempo de sobra, antes de la "vuelta al cole" en septiembre.

Aparte, espero que a alguien le pique la curiosidad y se lea el relato completo ([disponible aquí en inglés](https://www.utilitarianism.com/nu/omelas.pdf) y [aquí en español](http://antologiasinpoesia.blogspot.com/2013/07/los-que-se-van-de-omelas-de-ursula-k-le.html)), que es uno de mis relatos favoritos sobre el precio de la felicidad.

Que ustedes lo disfruten (tanto el relato como esta edición del [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf))

Comment: Muchas gracias por traer a Ursula K. Le Guin, me encanta, y este relato no lo conocía, sin duda lo leeré completo.

Comment: Hemos tenido un debate en [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46061/2017/8/30) sobre qué es el _it_ de _They all know it is there_. Finalmente @blonfu nos ha hecho ver que se refiere al niño cuya miseria es tan abominable.

Comment: @blonfu, gracias. Escribí este post muy tarde por la noche y así salió la traducción. Gracias por estar al tanto. Como bien indicas esa línea debería ser parte de la traducción.

Comment: @fedorqui, sí, poniendome al día con lo discutido en el chat creo que walen tiene razón y se usa como una especie de "género neutro". El relato es ambiguo a propósito (no solo con el género, sino con otras muchas cosas que pasan con la pobre criatura, ya que no hace falta saberlas. Lo que se dice es suficiente para invitar a la reflexión).

Comment: Me gustaría que constara en acta mi propuesta de traducción, que [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46061/) tuvo a bien celebrar: _Cómo mola Omelas, pena del niño_ :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### <strike>301 295 228 216 194 190 169 147 135</strike> 117 caracteres

> El niño está: debe. Su ruina es el bien de amistades, hijos, doctos, obreros, mies, cielo; beldad y ventura. Todo Omelas (viera, acepte, entienda o no) sabe.

*They all know it is there, all the people of Omelas.* -> El niño está: (...) Todo Omelas (...) sabe.
*Some of them have come to see it,* -> Todo Omelas (viera (...) o no)
*others are content merely to know it is there.* -> Todo Omelas (acepte (...) o no)
*They all know that it has to be there.* -> El niño está: debe. (...) Todo Omelas (...) sabe.
*Some of them understand why, and some do not,* -> Todo Omelas ((...) entienda o no)
*but they all understand that [enumeration] depend wholly on this child's abominable misery.* -> El niño (...). Su ruina es [enumeración]. Todo Omelas (...) sabe.
*their happiness,* -> ventura
*the beauty of their city,* -> beldad
*the tenderness of their friendships,* -> el bien de amistades
*the health of their children,* -> el bien de (...) hijos
*the wisdom of their scholars,* -> el bien de (...) doctos
*the skill of their makers,* -> el bien de (...) obreros
*even the abundance of their harvest* -> el bien de (...) mies
*and the kindly weathers of their skies,* -> el bien de (...) cielo

La enumeración del original describe lo más importante de cada cosa, la cualidad principal, lo que hace que sea bueno, su [bien](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=bien). El bien de la amistad es el cariño. El bien de los hijos es que estén sanos. El bien de los doctos es la sabiduría. El bien del obrero es su habilidad. El bien de la cosecha es ser abundante. El bien del cielo es que haga buen tiempo.

<sub>El resto de explicaciones se pueden ver en el historial de ediciones.</sub>

Comment: Yo creo que esa elipsis lo fuerza un poco y debería ser "mas sí que está, y debe **estar**", ya que `debe` tiene otros muchos significados. Por otro lado, esa enumeración correlativa esa para quitarse el sombrero. Al principio no me creía que pudiese valer, y luego investigando un poco más vi que era un uso brillante de ese recurso literario. Bravo!! El transaltion-golf a veces nos hace tirar de ingenio y aprender un montón de cosas nuevas.

Comment: Eres un crack! Esto está llegando al límite si no ha llegado ya.

Comment: 169 caracteres O_O. Mis respetos caballero *(reverencia)*.

Comment: De momento no sabría como superar eso, tendría que bajar 15 caracteres y mis palabras ya son bastante cortas, por ese lado poco que rascar. Ya no diré que es imposible pero lo tengo muy complicado.

Comment: Es culpa tuya por darme pistas.

Comment: Buen trabajo, madre mía.

Comment: Entiendo que "está y debe y ya" es la nueva versión corregida de "está y debe". No tengo problemas con el texto.

Comment: Anda ya!  Este juego va a acabar conmigo

Comment: Iba a publicar mi propia respuesta pero creo que ya me voy a esperar al siguiente juego... Madre mía la que estáis armando @blonfu y tú...

Comment: Falta ciudad ahí, no? Por lo demás no tengo palabras, aunque visto lo visto ni falta que hacen.

Comment: Creo que aún te sobra una palabra en *viera, acepte o entienda*

Comment: ¡Enhorabuena! Ha sido una dura batalla, al principio con muchos participantes, luego VeAqui metiendo presión y el sprint final reduciendo por encima de nuestras posibilidades ha sido demencial. Me lo he pasado en grande con este juego.

Answer (score 5):

**<strike>350 310 300 289 226 210 194 183 169 159 140</strike> 123 caracteres**

> La dicha, bella ciudad, amistad, hijos sanos, sabios, artistas,
>   gran siega y buen clima de Omelas nacen del drama del niño, lo saben,
>   debe estar, aun sin verlo.

---

En el *aun sin verlo* del final juego con dos significados diferentes a la vez (¿es trampa?) ya que por una parte no todos van a ver al niño y algunos no entienden el porqué de todo eso.

Comment: increíble golfeo :O si cambias `Unos lo ven, otros no, pero todos ` por `No todos lo entienden, pero ` ahorras 3 caracteres, ya mira tu si crees que pierde el sentido original o no ;) (De hecho, si sigues usando el verbo ver, ahorras aun mas(280))

Comment: Madre mía. Si es que hacéis que esto sea más interesante que un Madrid-Barsa. Es increíble cómo has reducido no solo las tres primeras frases del texto original en una, si no cómo has resuelto el resto sin recurrir a la enumeración correlativa ya utilizada por Walen.

Comment: @Diego, esa era la idea, no usar el recurso de la enumeración correlativa porque a mi no se me hubiera ocurrido. Pensaba que no iba a poder encontrar algo para superar eso y usar adjetivos tal vez cambie ligeramente el sentido de la frase pero no me quedaba otra opción que intentarlo.

Comment: ¡¡¡He oído empate!!! Vamos a necesitar _photo finish_ para determinar quién gana :)

Comment: @walen vale, pues lo pongo, no lo veo nada claro en realidad pero que hable el pueblo o Diego en última instancia.

Comment: Para que quede constancia, tampoco veo nada malo en esta traducción. Como dije en otro comentario andaba preocupado porque pensaba que el texto no era adecuado y me habéis sorprendido, gratamente, con fabulosa habilidad en todos los post (y sucesivos updates) de esta entrada del juego.

Answer (score 4):

**<strike>302</strike> 300 caracteres**

> Todo Omelas sabe que está allí; algunos lo han venido a ver, a otros les vale con saberlo. Todos lo aceptan: algunos captan por qué, otros no; pero todos infieren que su felicidad, gracia de su urbe, afecto de sus amigos, salud de su prole, saber de sus doctos, maña de sus obreros, hasta la riqueza de su cosecha y el buen clima, dependen totalmente de la feroz miseria de aquel niño

Mi primera vez...

Answer (score 4):

**<strike>225</strike> <strike>204</strike> <strike>192</strike> <strike>186</strike> <strike>184</strike> 175 Caracteres**

> Todo Omelas sabe. Unos lo vieron, otros dejan que esté ahí. ¿Sabrán por qué? Vale que su suerte, alegría, bella ciudad, amor, hijos sanos, grandes sabios, hábiles peones, fértiles cosechas y buen clima son por el niño jodido

Para vencer a estos 2 genios, solo @fedorqui... pero si me les acerco otro poco, no hace daño (lo que si hace daño es que quizá les quité alguna palabra)

- Las 2 primeras frases en inglés se pueden remplazar con *Todo Omelas
  lo sabe* y puede quitarse el pronombre, ya que luego hablaremos del
  objeto llamado por el pronombre.
- En la tercera frase, se menciona que le han visto y a cambio de reir (como muestra de su regocijo) decidí con que la gente de Omelas lo deje estar.
- Para remplazar desde el segundo punto hasta el understand, se plantea la pregunta para dar a entender que no todos lo saben y el vale en la segunda acepción del DRAE (producir, dar ganancias o interés)
- Al usar su suerte se evitan unos 7 u 8 posesivos... (entre 5 y 15 caracteres) y se usa con su 3ra acepción del Drae (suerte favorable)
- Lo que Omelas sabe, el motivo de su felicidad, lo dejé (aunque malsonante) en "el niño jodido"

Si alguna frase falta o creen que haya algún error, me comentan... y veremos si puedo robarle 20 caracteres en 48 horas...

Comment: Genial primera contribución. Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]

Comment: Bienvenido al juego y a *Spanish Language*, te has puesto en cabeza rápidamente.  Estaría bien que explicaras los cambios que puedan causar más dudas ya que el objetivo es mantener todo lo posible el sentido original.

Comment: Saludos a todos y gracias, acerca de los cambios para mantener el sentido son de basarse en que las gentes del pueblo saben que son felices, en que consiste esa felicidad y el motivo. Ya en el mensaje iré describiendo las palabras o frases más puntuales

Comment: error de acepción en el ser... es el problema de jugar tetris con el diccionario...

Comment: en esos términos, no aplica aunque no he leído todavía todo el relato, estaba solo con el fragmento que nos acercó @Diego... por otro lado, mis respetos walen, no puedo comentar todavía en tu entrada(apenas entré hace 23 horas...) pero lo manejas bastante bien (quiza le puedes bajar uno o 2 caracteres...)

Comment: Aún sin leer el relato no dice que estén contentos, dice que "se contentan con saber" 
o "se conforman con saber" que es muy diferente: *others are content merely to know it is there.*

Answer (score 3):

Traducción rapidita, lo siento si se parece mucho a alguna otra, esta vez no he leído ninguna con tal de no "contaminarme". A ver si luego hago otra tomando unas pocas libertades que he visto posibles.

### <strike>371 364</strike> 353 caracteres

> Todo Omelas sabe que está ahí. Unos vienen a verlo, otros se bastan con saber que está. Todos saben que debe estar, aunque no todos lo entienden. Pero todos entienden que su felicidad, la belleza de su ciudad, la ternura de sus amistades, la salud de sus hijos, la sabiduría de sus sabios, la habilidad de sus productores, incluso la abundancia de sus cosechas y la bondad del tiempo, dependen completamente de la abominable miseria del niño.

- al decir `aunque no todos`, se puede asumir que algunos si, por lo que no se pierde el sentido original de "algunos si entienden, otros no".
- Corrijo "todo amelas saben" por "todo amelas sabe", fallo tonto, pero metía un caracter mas :p
- Cambio "otros se contentan" por "otros se bastan".
- Cambio "algunos vienen" por "unos vienen".
- Cambio "Aunque no todos entienden por qué" por "aunque no todos lo entienden".

Comment: Donde puedo localizar el script que hace el recuento de caracteres?

Comment: Está en la propia pregunta pero te lo pongo aquí también: https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/

Comment: No hace falta que mantengas todas las versiones. Si quisieras recuperar alguna frase anterior hay un historial de ediciones con todos los cambios

Answer (score 2):

<strike>383  274</strike> **254 caracteres**

> Los Omelas lo saben, aunque no todos han venido, a algunos les basta saberlo. La mayoría capta que la felicidad, la belleza, el afecto, la salud, la sabiduría y el talento correspondientes a olmelitas, ciudad, relaciones, hijos, sabios y artistas, incluso cosechas y la merced del clima dependen de la miseria del niño.

- He agrupado las 3 primeras frases con la idea que contienen
- He cambiado la parte de unos entienden, otros no, pero todos entienden por "la mayoría capta"

Primera vez que participo.

Comment: Una duda. En las normas indica que hay que mantener la estructura pero parece que todo el mundo resumen y quita frases. qué se valora? contenido o el tema? @walen

Comment: Recomiendo que cambies el principio por "Todo Omelas sabe que está aunque no todos. . .", y has escrito "climan" en vez de clima.