# Translation Golf XXX - The Gunslinger

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

> ¡Fin del juego! Respuesta ganadora: [la de Charlie con 122 caracteres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/24030/translation-golf-xxx-the-gunslinger/24038#24038).

---

Bienvenidos a una nueva edición del [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf). El texto escogido en esta ocasión es de la novela de Stephen King "The Gunslinger", primer libro de su aclamada serie de "La Torre Oscura".

> The greatest mystery the universe offers is not life but size. Size encompasses life, and the Tower encompasses size. The child, who is most at home with wonder, says: Daddy, what is above the sky? And the father says: The darkness of space. The child: What is beyond space? The father: The galaxy. The child: Beyond the galaxy? The father: Another galaxy. The child: Beyond the other galaxies? The father: No one knows [...] Everything in the universe denies nothing; to suggest an ending is the one absurdity.

Traducción libre en español (422 caracteres):

> El mayor misterio que presenta el universo no es la vida, sino el tamaño. El tamaño abarca la vida, y la Torre abarca el tamaño. El niño, que se siente a gusto con lo maravilloso, pregunta: ¿Qué hay más allá del cielo, papá? Y el padre contesta: La oscuridad del espacio. El niño: ¿Qué hay más allá del espacio? El padre: La galaxia. El niño: ¿Más allá de la galaxia? El padre: Otra galaxia. El niño: ¿Y más allá de las demás galaxias? El padre: Nadie lo sabe. ¿Lo ves? [...] Todo en el universo desmiente la nada. Sugerir una conclusión a las cosas es lo absurdo.

Esto es [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf), la traducción con menor número de caracteres que respete el sentido del texto original gana.

Que ustedes lo disfruten.

---

- Recordatorio de las normas: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Link para contar caracteres: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

---

En un principio había pensado volver a traer algo de Ursula K. Le Guin, quizá [visitando de nuevo Omelas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21982/5481) o con algo de *La mano izquierda de la oscuridad*, en plan homenaje debido a su reciente fallecimiento. Sin embargo, me decidí por mi fragmento favorito (casi un pasaje que salva toda la novela...) de este libro de Stephen King.

El texto es un poco largo, pero dada la brevedad del [pasaje de último juego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23877/5481), quería volver a poner algo que permitiese múltiples *edits* para mejorar el *post* propio y ponerse de nuevo al frente de los competidores. Creo que hay juegos que se resuelven muy pronto porque uno no ve cómo golfear su texto sin reutilizar algo que ya haya usado otro competidor, y quizá con un texto más largo tengamos más oportunidad de participar y buscar la manera de *golfear* nuestros textos. Creo que este texto invita a aguzar el ingenio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### <strike>216 180 169</strike> 122 caracteres

> La Torre ha tamaño, [quid](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UpHbqdL) del [mundo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Q5etWXp), y vida pues. Papá oye al terco niño: «—¿Qué oculta el [azul](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4hL0yKW)? —El espacio [fusco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IdyosrI). —¿Y este? —Galaxias. —¿Y...? —Más. —¿Y...? —A saber.» [...] ¿La "nada"? [Tonta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a1laMnE) idea.

Comentarios interesantes:

- Definición de *quid*: esencia, punto más importante o porqué de una cosa.
- El DLE admite *azul* como sinónimo poético de *cielo* (esfera de aparente color azul que rodea la Tierra).
- La palabra *mundo* proviene del latín *mundus*, que es un calco de la palabra griega *κόσμος kósmos*, de ahí que su primera acepción sea "conjunto de todo lo existente".
- La palabra *tonto* tiene una acepción que es "carente de sentido", luego equivale a *absurdo*.

Comment: Eres el ganador!! Enhorabuena. Ya conoces el proceso, nos vemos en el siguiente juego!

Answer (score 6):

#### <s>308 261 210 190</s>  133 caracteres

> La Torre tiene tamaño (que es la clave) y este vida. El niño al papá:
>   --¿Qué hay tras el cielo? --El espacio ,la galaxia, otra galaxia y luego ni idea. [...] Nada es nada; un fin es absurdo.

Comment: +1 por "arcano": me has descubierto que, a pesar de haber oído la palabra antes, no tenía ni idea de lo que significaba.

Comment: @Charlie Tendría que haber puesto enlace al DLE entonces, creía que todos la entenderían.

Comment: Cierto, se agradecería el enlace a "arcano" http://dle.rae.es/?id=3RkM52P +1 también por "flipado".

Answer (score 4):

#### <s>196</s> 138 caracteres

> La Torre ha tamaño, que es vida, y la clave. Va el niño absorto: «—Papi,
> ¿qué hay tras el cielo? —Negro cosmos. —¿Y pues? —Galaxia. —¿Y pues? —Más. —¿Y pues? —No se sabe.» (...) Decir "nada" es bobo: todo la niega.

Comment: Impresionante la forma en la que has mantenido el diálogo, y aun así _golfeado_ el texto al máximo!

Answer (score 4):

**171 caracteres**

> La Torre como el tamaño y no la vida es el enigma del cosmos. Dice el niño:
>   «—¿Papá, tras el cielo qué hay? —El cosmos. —¿Qué más? —Galaxia.
>   —¿Y de eso? —Otra. —¿Y luego? —Incognito.» (...)
>   Todo el cosmos niega el nulo; es tonto sugerir un fin.

Ya llevo algo de tiempo sin participar en uno de estos. Aquí va el primer intento.

Comment: Buen comienzo, pero la verdad es que echo en falta la lógica de "con tamaño hay vida"; y la de "con la Torre hay tamaño" la veo algo ofuscada. ¿Podrías explicar la traducción a ese respecto?

Comment: @Charlie Es requisito entender que la locución **X como Y** indica que X es representativo de Y, y en este caso, La Torre representa tamaño, y el tamaño es el enigma del cosmos y no la vida. Pero, creo entender a lo que te refieres.

Answer (score 3):

**214 chars**

Vamos a jugar un poco, a poner palabras y recursos interesantes

> ¿Vida? no, El lío total es tamaño. Vida en el tamaño, en la torre. El niño hogareño dice: ¿Papi, qué hay tras el cielo? Su papá: El negro espacio. El niño: ¿detrás? Su papá: La galaxia. El niño: ¿y sigue? Su papá: Otra galaxia. El niño: ¿Y...? Su papá: Nadie sabe (...) El universo niega la nada, ¿borde? vano

- vano viene en su 7ma acepción
- total por universal
- la última pregunta asume un padre desesperado que no deja terminar a su hijo (voy a creer que no me valdrán el recurso, pero al menos debo intentarlo)